# Android : Dynamic listview howto?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Need some idea tackling a problem with listview.

```
Person 1   ----> Pet 1
           ----> Pet 2
           ----> Pet 3

Person 2   ----> Pet 1

Person 3   ----> Pet 1
           ----> Pet 2
           ----> Pet 3
           ----> Pet 4
```

How is it possible so that I can display the above hierarchy in a listview like this:

```
Person 1 row
   Pet 1 row
   Pet 2 row
   Pet 3 row
```

and so on.

I have thought about expandable listview, but that will not really suit my needs. Is there a way to achieve the layout I need?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Can you include a practical example with real data?

Comment: you need to use a custom list adapter. Either use a tab for the pets or load a separate view for pets/people. This tutorial is great: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: did you check out expandableListView? You could use a person as group and related pets as child elements

Answer (score 0):

Why expandable list is not suit you? You don't want an "expand" feature of `ExpandableListView`?
You want just simple `ListView` with two types of `ListView` items?

If so, I think the best way is use `ListView` in such a way.

Define for example `enum`:

```
enum ListViewItemType {
    PERSON, PET
}
```

and method:

```
private ListViewItemType getTypeByPosition(int position);
```

For example, if you have such structure:

```
Person 1 row
Pet 1 row
Pet 2 row
Pet 3 row
Person 2 row
Pet 1 row
etc.
```

this method will return:

```
0: PERSON
1: PET
2: PET
3: PET
4: PERSON
5: PET
etc.
```

Think about how to implement this method :)

Then create `Adapter` for `ListView` and override its `getView(...)` method

```
.. getView(int, View, ViewGroup)  {
    switch(getTypeByPosition(position)) {
        PERSON: // return view for person listview item
        PET: // return view for pet listview item
}
```

That's is.
If you need more detailed explanation, just ask)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I fully understand what you want to achieve, but based on your example, it would probably make the most sense to use a header for each person and list their respective pet's below. To do this, you will need to construct a data structure (probably an ArrayList in your case) with all pets listed and ordered by their owner.

One nice way you could achieve this visually would be to utilize a library like https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders, where each owner's header view would "stick" above their group of pets.